# How to make a graph strongly connected by swapping its edges

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph, directed-graph

How can I calculate the number of steps required to make a directed graph strongly connected by swapping edges? A step is an edge swap.

**Note:** Every node will have an in-degree of 1 and an out-degree of 1.

**Eg->**  `1->3`, `2->1`, `3->2` and `4->4` is **not** strongly connected. Now, if we swap `4->1` and `2->4` then it becomes strongly connected.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your question. Could you elaborate more and post your code here?

Comment: Is it necessary, that every node will have **1** in-degree and **1**  out-degree. because you have explained such eg.

Comment: Yes it is given that every node will have 1 in-degree and 1 out-degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the solution goes like this:

- First, calculate `total` number of **disjoint cycles or loops** in the graph you have *let say the number of disjoint cycle or loops are **N***.
- Print **N-1**, that would be your answer to this question. (`N-1` **Why ?** Think).

Comment: Means if there is **one** cycle, then your require **zero** swap